# Matplotlib 2 inconsistent font

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I updated Anaconda Python to the latest version (4.3), where they upgraded Matplotlib to version 2.

The upgrade has made some major changes to the default style ([see here](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html)).
And, while I really like some of those changes, I am not in agreement with a few of them.

Hence I did some modifications, as suggested in the link above:

```
#%matplotlib inline
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html
params = {'legend.fontsize': 18,
          'axes.labelsize': 18,
          'axes.titlesize': 18,
          'xtick.labelsize' :12,
          'ytick.labelsize': 12,
          'mathtext.fontset': 'cm',
          'mathtext.rm': 'serif',
          'grid.color': 'k',
          'grid.linestyle': ':',
          'grid.linewidth': 0.5,
         }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)

x = sc.linspace(0,100)
y = x**2
fig = plt.figure('Fig')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.semilogy(x, y)
ax.set_yticks([300], minor=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=10)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{R_L}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma \int_l \; dx$')
#fig.savefig('./PNG/test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Using Latex as the axes labels, as in the code above, results in a figure with inconsistent text on axes (see the following image).

[image]

How to get back to the previous behaviour (see the image below) or to a consistent font scheme?

[image]

**EDIT**:
Using the Latex back-end I am able to get a good result, but it is extremely slow. 
Anyway, I think the internal back-end should be able to get a consistent output and switching to a different back-end is not a real solution, but more a workaround.

To use the latex back-end:

```
#%matplotlib inline
#%matplotlib notebook
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html
params = {'legend.fontsize': 18,
          'axes.labelsize': 18,
          'axes.titlesize': 18,
          'xtick.labelsize' :12,
          'ytick.labelsize': 12,
          'mathtext.fontset': 'cm',
          'mathtext.rm': 'serif',
          'grid.color': 'k',
          'grid.linestyle': ':',
          'grid.linewidth': 0.5,
         }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex':True, 'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{amsmath, newtxmath}']})

x = sc.linspace(0,100)
y = x**2
fig = plt.figure('Fig')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.semilogy(x, y)
ax.set_yticks([300], minor=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=10)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{R_L}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma \int_l \; dx$')
#fig.savefig('./PNG/test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The result with matplotlib 2 is:

[image]

The resulting plot with the older version is (still a bit different, maybe due to some latex differences):

[image]

But again, the desired result is what obtained from an older version of matplotlib and in displayed in figure 2.

Comment: The documentation that you link to says "The default math font when using the built-in math rendering engine (mathtext) has changed from “Computer Modern” (i.e. LaTeX-like) to “DejaVu Sans”." In other words, the _default_ behaviour should be a sans-serif font like your bottom graph. It looks like `'mathtext.rm': 'serif'` is the cause, removing it should fix the issue.

Comment: I tried that change but the output is the same.

Comment: I couldn't replicate so I tried to upgrade matplotlib and it's now very helpfully removed my `numpy` installation so I can't test anything. But the math font section also mentions `'mathtext.fontset': 'cm'` so maybe remove that too. I can't work out what that line does.

Comment: If I remove that I get everything to unicode, which I do not like.
I would like to keep a latex font for latex things and labels, but the axes number as before (as in the second plot). To update anaconda to the last version I preferred to reinstall from scratch, sometimes is better...

Comment: I'm in Canopy but I would have expected it to be reproducible if I had the latest `matplotlib`. However, I can't see anything in the documentation now that makes it clear how to achieve both of your objectives, so maybe I don't want to upgrade because it seems an illogical mismatch with no clear way to fix it.#

Comment: The question doesn't have any latex in. In order to provide you with a working solution, we would need an example case which does produce the desired result in matplotlib 1.5, but doesn't in 2.0, **including** latex if that matters for you.

Comment: Edited adding latex as requested.

Comment: I haven't found anything on github that looks related to this issue. I have tried `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` and get `RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string: lp`. That was the last thing I could see in the docs there that might have helped so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If you would like to use Latex try: `matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex':True, 'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{amsmath, newtxmath}']})`.
But it is slow and I prefer the builtin method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to find a solution to my question, I tried comparing the dictionaries of the old and new rcParams and setting the elements which were different and related to mathtext font: the result is quite good.

The code is:

```
#%matplotlib inline
#%matplotlib notebook
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html
params = {'legend.fontsize': 18,
          'axes.labelsize': 18,
          'axes.titlesize': 18,
          'xtick.labelsize' :12,
          'ytick.labelsize': 12,
          'mathtext.fontset': 'cm',
          'mathtext.rm': 'serif',
          'mathtext.bf': 'serif:bold',
          'mathtext.it': 'serif:italic',
          'mathtext.sf': 'sans\\-serif',
          'grid.color': 'k',
          'grid.linestyle': ':',
          'grid.linewidth': 0.5,
         }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)
#matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex':True, 'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{amsmath, newtxmath}']})
#matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex':True, 'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{amsmath, mathptmx}']})
#matplotlib.rcParams.update({'text.usetex':True, 'text.latex.preamble':[r'\usepackage{amsmath}']})

x = sc.linspace(0,100)
y = x**2
fig = plt.figure('Fig')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.semilogy(x, y)
ax.set_yticks([300], minor=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=10)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{R_L}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma \int_l \; dx$')
fig.savefig('./PNG/test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

hence adding also:

```
          'mathtext.rm': 'serif',
          'mathtext.bf': 'serif:bold',
          'mathtext.it': 'serif:italic',
          'mathtext.sf': 'sans\\-serif',
```

which results in:

[image]

that I consider quite good and consistent in a Latex document.

The other [answer in this thread from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254361/732471) is also neat and nice.

Answer (score 4):

If consistency is the only issue, you can use a "Roman" style using the "Times" font. It is not necessary to use Latex via `usetex`. Instead simply use the STIX fontset, the Times font and serif mathtext.

```
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

params = {'legend.fontsize': 18,
          'axes.labelsize': 18,
          'axes.titlesize': 18,
          'xtick.labelsize' :12,
          'ytick.labelsize': 12,
          'grid.color': 'k',
          'grid.linestyle': ':',
          'grid.linewidth': 0.5,
          'mathtext.fontset' : 'stix',
          'mathtext.rm'      : 'serif',
          'font.family'      : 'serif',
          'font.serif'       : "Times New Roman", # or "Times"          
         }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)

x = sc.linspace(0,100)
y = x**2
fig = plt.figure('Fig')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.semilogy(x, y)

ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=10)
ax.set_yticks([300], minor=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathrm{R_L}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma \int_l \; dx$')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Neat, the output is nice and consistent. In the meanwhile I tried comparing the dictionaries of the rcParam and I tried setting the different elements: the result is quite good. I will try to put this as possible answer to myself (without accepting my self answer, since I do not feel it as definitive).

Answer (score 1):

From the link you did provide:

> A ‘classic’ style sheet is provided so reverting to the 1.x default values is a single line of python
>
> mpl.style.use('classic')

Adding this line

```
matplotlib.style.use('classic')
```

to your script should solve your problem.

I tested it on my python2.7/matplotlib 2, and it worked fine (i.e. I get back the matplotlib 1.x fonts).

Comment: Yes, but it is the really old style. You do not obtain the same style as in the second plot.
I would like to keep the new style and fix the font issue.

Comment: @Alex: I thought you meant the axes ticks only. See http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#fonts for more details on the fonts. Changing your code to `'mathtext.fontset': 'stixsans',` and/or `'mathtext.rm': 'sansserif',`  produce pretty good results to me.

Comment: But the latex in the labels has a different font, which is ugly.