# Matplotlib style inconsistency

Tags: matplotlib

Before updating Anaconda to new version graphs were looking like the figure (left). After update grids, axes font, line thickness and label were changed (right picture). However, today it started to give the left figure (older) again even that code of two graphs is the same. I want to keep the latest styles except font-family from old version (marked in figures). Why does this happening how do I get control?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt
import matplotlib  as mpl


data = loadtxt("ES1-10sr_CV.txt",float)

potential = data[:,0]
current_density = data[:,1]
current_density = current_density*1e6

ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)


plt.plot(potential,current_density, color="blue")


plt.xlabel(r'$\mathrm{V_f \ (V \ vs. \ Ref.)}$', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Current \ Density} \ (\mu{A}/cm^2$)', fontsize=16)

#plt.legend(loc=4,prop={'size':14}, 
          # ncol=1, shadow=True, fancybox=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()


mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})



plt.savefig('ES1-10sr_CV.tiff', dpi=1000, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Comparations of images]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249945/matplotlib-2-inconsistent-font/42251781#42251781

Comment: @Moritz I'll check the link you provided.

Comment: @Moritz thank you for the link. I edited params to get the view which I wanted.